# XSS and htmlentities

Tags: javascript, xss, html-entities

```
$text = "( = \" ' & \\  </textarea> : ; . " ;

echo htmlentities($text);   

//outputs as -->>     ( = &quot; ' &amp; \  &lt;/textarea&gt; : ; . 

//obviously, htmlentities does nothing to ( ) = ; and .
```

htmlentities is a good line of defense but it does not help in javascript contexts.

wouldn't it be to write your own htmlencode function to further enforce ( ) . ; and = characters to be encoed as well?

This way, one function would make you safe across the board. I want to hear if there are issues going with that approach.

I assume that you cannot possibly right javascript that would harm you without using one of the following 4 characters which are ( . ) ; =.

Comment: Are you putting user-generated content inside a `<script>` tag? That's very bad...

Comment: To _escape_ data in JavaScript use `json_encode`. `htmlentities` is incorrect, as is `addslashes`.

Answer (score 0):

> wouldn't it be to write your own htmlencode function to further enforce ( ) . ; and = characters to be encoed as well?

No. JavaScript is JavaScript and HTML is HTML.

The escape sequences needed to make data safe to put into JavaScript would cause extraneous characters to appear in the HTML.

The character references need to make data safe to put into HTML would either break JavaScript or cause incorrect characters to appear in the output of the JavaScript.

The only times it would make sense to use both functions would be when you were inserting raw data into JavaScript and then inserting that JavaScript into HTML or when you was inserting said data into HTML that was then inserted into JS. (Then the two functions would need to be run over the data in sequence and in the correct order).

> I assume that you cannot possibly right javascript that would harm you without using one of the following 4 characters which are ( . ) ; =.

Dangerous assumption

```
foo = [1,2,3];
Return value: [1, 2, 3]

Object--
Return value: NaN

foo = [1,2,3]
Error report: Uncaught TypeError: Object NaN has no method 'getOwnPropertyNames'
```

Comment: I see where my original question went off track. I was planning of using that function only in html context and by html context I meant not just the visible content area in html but also the tag content; example: <a href='user_generated_content_here' >text</a>. There, the user_generated_content_here needs to be correctly escaped. By taking care of those 4 chars which are namely ( ) ; and =, I thought I'd be safe against XSS. I can get some protection against XSS there such as javascript:alert(document.cookies). By adding . ( ), that would die right there.

Comment: { background-url : "javascript:alert(1)"; }  or { text-size: "expression(alert('XSS'))"; } . If I add the 4 characters I mentioned above, that javascript attempt would die. As to your [1,2,3] example, I'm not sure what your point was. What harm can you create without those 4 chars - especially in an html tag!

Comment: If you are putting data within javascript event handlers like onclick, you would still allow XSS: http://erlend.oftedal.no/blog/?blogid=124

Comment: @John Smith — If you are accepting a URI from the user then you need to make sure that it is a real URI, and that it uses an approved scheme (e.g. is an HTTP URI). You can't change a `(` character in a URI so that it wouldn't work in a `javascript:` URI without breaking an `http:` URI that includes that character.

Comment: @John Smith — My point was that if JavaScript executes, then it is possible to break object creation for the entire page without using `(`, `)`, `=` or `;`.

Comment: @Erlend — Which is why you need to suitably escape data before inserting it into JavaScript, as my answer said. There still isn't a way to make data safe for JavaScript, and for HTML, and for JavaScript in HTML and for HTML in JavaScript with a single function.

Comment: @Quentin - Yes, I was answering John Smith's comment just above mine. Sorry about the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

You need different encodings based on context. There is no "universal" encoder that could handle everything at once. It's not characters that are dangerous, it's context they're interpreted in.

Values in JavaScript require `json_encode($value)` (other functions like `addslashes()` won't handle all the edge cases. `json_encode` escapes `</` as required by HTML `<script>`).

Values in JavaScript in HTML attributes require both: `htmlspecialchars(json_encode($value))`, because each "layer" of syntax does it's own decoding when interpreting the data.